# Foreign field class does not have id field

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I get errors with the entities below (probably because of the relationship One To Many), but I do not see how to fix the problem.

**Course:**

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
Collection<Grade> grades;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "ID", canBeNull = false)
private long id;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "LABEL", canBeNull = false)
private String label;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "COEFFICIENT", canBeNull = false, defaultValue = "1")
private float coefficient;
```

**Grade:**

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "ID_COURSE", canBeNull = false, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
Course course;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "ID", canBeNull = false)
private long id;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "DATE", canBeNull = false)
private Date date;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "GRADE", canBeNull = false, defaultValue = "1")
private float grade;
```

When launching the app and trying to fetch datas from database :

> Foreign field class Course does not have id field

Comment: Perhaps add `foreignColumnName = "ID"` to your `@DatabaseField` annotation on `Grade.course`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Course class has to have id field

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "ID")
Long id;
```

or make your existing field id as id by:

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "ID", canBeNull = false)
private long id;
```